# How can I only insert a record if it does not exists?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently making a simple IP banning script and I am at the stage of inserting the IP address into the database. The HTML form I created for this consists of two fields; the IP address and a reason:

```
<td width="70%"><h4>Ban New IP:</h4>(Enter IP to be banned)</td>
    <td width="30%">
    <form method="post" action="">
     IP Address: <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15" /><br /><br />
     Enter Reason: <input type="text" id="reason" name="reason" autocomplete="off" maxlength="255" /><br /><br />
     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ban IP" /><br /><br />
```

My database contains one table titled `banned_ips` and three columns `id, ip and reason`. The insert statement I have created works perfectly however I want to check to see if the IP already exists. At the moment it will just insert the IP even if there is one matching it. This is my current query:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    if ($_POST['ip'] != '') {
        if (strlen($_POST['ip']) <= 15) {
            $ip = $_POST['ip'];

            $ip_clean = htmlentities($ip);

            if (isset($ip_clean)) {
                // SQL insert
                $insert_ip = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `banned_ips` (ip) VALUES (?)");
                $insert_ip->bind_param('s', $ip_clean);

                if ($insert_ip->execute()) {
                    // Successful insert
                    $_SESSION['successful_insert'] = 'Success';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```

What I would like to do is check to see if the IP address already exists when they go to insert a new IP. I have looked at other questions asked here on stackoverflow and a lot of the time I saw `WHERE NOT EXISTS` however none that I found showed any examples with prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make `ip` field a unique field.

`mysql` will then prevent duplication

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` may be helpful in this case, since an intentional failure to insert a duplicate value isn't really an error condition.

Comment: That's it?  What about handling the inevitable errors that occur?

Comment: @RobertHarvey then you can also check the table like roun512 [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23478600/1880431)

Comment: if you put `$execute = $insert_ip->execute(); if(!$execute) { echo "error"; } won't it work ? i mean incase you make ip unique, i think it will

Answer (score 2):

You can make the ip column `UNIQUE` and by doing that if the same IP exists it won't insert it or by doing query like this :

```
$check_ip = $db->prepare("SELECT `ip` FROM `banned_ips` WHERE `ip` = ?");
$check_ip->bind_param('s', $ip_clean);
$res = $check_ip->execute();
if($res) {
    echo "IP Already exists";
} else {
    //insert it to db
}
```

If you put the code then first it will check if the IP exists, if it exists it will not insert else if it doesn't exist it will insert it to the db.

Comment: While this type of solution is often useful, it suffers from race conditions if there is more than one updater.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way:

1) make ip a unique key, than when you Will try to write the same ip, statement, return you an error.

2) make a previously query, to check if the ip is alredy stored in your table.

Anyway the first solution is the best!

Bye

Comment: Not really, if you choose the first solution then you can't handle errors, but in 2nd way you can handle them.